# How to catch the DAO Service Layer Exception cleanly in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-data-jpa

Would like to check on the DAO Service Layer Implementation for Exception Handling in Spring Data JPA.

The functional module which is using the DAO service layer interface isn't a GUI, hence we need the DAO Service layer expception to be caught transparently (Some error message to be written to the log file). The functional module isn't going to take any action for DAO layer exception, hence I want to catch the exceptions by the DAO service layer itselves..

Comment: In your service layer you are doing the exception handling and validation before you are calling the DAO layer. It seems you understand this, so what is your question? You don't have specific example leaves this question becomes hard to answer and likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is log the exception, then you could use an Advice which would log exceptions in DAO lays, something like:

```
@Aspect
public class ExceptionLogginAspect {

    @AfterThrowing(value = "execution(* x.y.dao.*(*))", throwing = "ex")
    public void afterThrowing(Exception ex){
        //log exception here
    }
}
```